# how to use dock window & non-dock together

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, window, dock

I need some part of UI to behave like dock window, but not all. I wonder if that's possible to mix the two. Say, I want 3 datagrids to be fixed in their positions, but I want settings windows to dock on right side or in middle of main window, when mouse hovers on it, it will expand and show all settings, when mouse moves away, the setting window simply collapses. but I do not want the other 3 data grids to move or collapse. I'd like the data grid show up as normal, not like a dock document.
Thanks

Edit

My project uses both WPF and WinForms. So I am looking for solutions for both

Comment: take a look at AvalonDock.

Comment: Please clarify if this is WPF or WinForms. You've used both tags.

Answer (score 0):

Just dock the settings to the right and listen to the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events. Change the width of the settings to zero, or something very small, when MouseLeave, and back to full width on MouseEnter.

Resizing a docked control behaves very nicely.